# como cerrar sesión en proyecto "BilleteraVirtual"?

Tags: java, clase, metodos

hola como podría hacer para cerrar sesión y también tengo dudas en como autenticar el inicio de sesión,el inicio de sesión me salio y creo que puede funcionar,tengo dudas en los otros 2 métodos...les dejo como esta conformada la clase.

```
public class Operador {

private String nombre;
private String apellido;
private String nickName;
private String contrasenia;
private boolean habilitadoParaRealizarTransacciones;
//AGREGO ESTOS ATIRBUTOS


/*
 * Constructor. Se deben generar los atributos necesarios para el correcto
 * funcionamiento.
 */
public Operador(String nombre, String apellido, String nickName, String contrasenia,
        boolean habilitadoParaRealizarTransacciones) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.nickName = nickName;
    this.contrasenia = contrasenia;
    this.habilitadoParaRealizarTransacciones = true;

}

/**
 * Realiza la validación del nick y la contraseña para iniciar sesión
 * 
 * @param nickName    String Nombre de usuario
 * @param contrasenia String Contraseña del usuario
 * @return Verdadero en caso de exito
 */
public boolean iniciarSesion(String nickName, String contrasenia) {

    boolean sePudoIniciarSesion = false;

    if (getNickName().equals(nickName) && getContrasenia().equals(contrasenia)) {
        sePudoIniciarSesion = true;
    }
    return sePudoIniciarSesion;

}

/**
 * Cierra la sesión del operador
 * 
 * @return boolean Verdadero en caso de exito
 */
public boolean cerrarSesion() {
    
    boolean exito=false;
    
    if(iniciarSesion(nickName, contrasenia) == true) {
        exito=true;
        
    }
    return exito;
}

/**
 * Verifica si el usuario tiene la sesión iniciada
 * 
 * @return boolean Verdadero en caso de estar autenticado
 */
public boolean estaAutenticado() {
    
    return false;
}
```

los métodos en los cuales tengo dudas son los últimos 2 de abajo de la clase,esta comentado las instrucciones para resolverlos.Tambien les dejo la clase main ya que en el menu de opciones para dar de alta un operador,debe estar autenticado.

*clase main

```
public class InterfazBilleteraVirtual {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    System.out.println("Bienvenido a la billetera Bin Ance.");
    
    int opcion = 0;
    do {
        opcion = seleccionarOpcion();
        switch (opcion) {
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2: 
            // TODO: Si no esta autenticado, no puede realizar las siguiente operaciones. Se debe mostrar el nombre y apellido
            break;
        case 3:
            // TODO: Mostrar mensaje en caso de exito o error
            break;
        case 4:
            // TODO: Mostrar mensaje en caso de exito o error
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
        case 6:
            break;
        case 7:
            break;
        case 9:
            // TODO: Se debe cerrar la sesión del operador
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Opcion Invalida");
            break;
        }

    } while (opcion != 9);
    
    System.out.println("Hasta pronto!");
}

private static int seleccionarOpcion() {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    int opcionSeleccionada=0;
    
    System.out.println("************************");
    System.out.println("Menu de Transacciones Virtuales\n");
    System.out.println("1 - Dar de alta un Operador ");
    System.out.println("2 - Iniciar sesion"); 
    System.out.println("3 - Comprar criptomoneda"); 
    System.out.println("4 - Vender criptomoneda");
    System.out.println("5 - Informar el saldo de criptomonedas");
    System.out.println("6 - Informar la transaccion de criptomonedas de mayor monto");
    System.out.println("7 - Listar las transacciones de criptomonedas ordenadas descendientemente");
    System.out.println("9 - Salir");
    System.out.println("************************");
    System.out.println("Ingrese una opcion");
    
    opcionSeleccionada = teclado.nextInt();
    
    return opcionSeleccionada;
}
```

}

siempre me resulta un poco mas difícil resolver la clase main,pero en este caso esos 2 métodos me están complicando.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos por partes.

```
public Operador( String nomb, String apell, String nick, String pass, boolean habilitado ) {
    nombre = nomb;
    apellido = apell;
    nickName = nick;
    contrasenia = pass;
    habilitadoParaRealizarTransacciones = habilitado;    
}
```

Como verás, yo prefiero evitar el uso de "this", eso me evita muchos errores que son difíciles de encontrar (aunque puedes usarlo, si te parece mejor), el cambio importante, es instanciar **habilitadoParaRealizarTransacciones** con el parámetro que se le pasa al método, osea **habilitado**.

```
public boolean iniciarSesion( String nickName, String pass ) {    
    if( nickName.equals( nick ) && contrasenia.equals( pass )) {
        return = true;
    }
    return false;    
}
```

Aquí, cambio el **getNickName()** y el **getContrasenia()**, por las respectivas variables, los getters y los setters, se crean para ser llamados desde otra clase, puedes usarlos como los usas... solo que escribes más código y suele ser más confuso, también elimino **sePudoIniciarSesion**, y retorno directamente el valor que corresponde.

```
public void cerrarSesion() {    
    autenticado = false;
}
```

Este método no tiene que devolver nada, solo debe evitar que el usuario haga algo.

```
public boolean estaAutenticado() {    
    return autenticado;
}

boolean autenticado = false;
```

Acá simplemente devolvemos el valor de la variable **autenticado**... que debemos crear.

Para finalizar, vamos con el main, solo te voy a dar una guía...

case 1: pedir los datos al usuario para crear un nuevo usuario llamando a **Operador**, le debes pasar como parámetros, los datos recibidos.

case 2: pides al usuario nombre y pass, y con esos parámetros llamas a **iniciarSesion**.

case 3: debes pedir la cantidad de criptos a comprar, y llamar a **comprarCriptos**, con ese valor... obviamente primero debes crear el método, que debe aumentar el saldo e instanciar el primer lugar vacio el array **historial** (no estará vacio, sino que tendra valor "0").

case 4: similar al anterior.

case 5: debes llamar al método **getSaldo**, crearlo así como un atributo **saldo = 0;** en la clase.

case 6: acá estás obligado a crear un atributo (un array) que contenga el historial de los montos de las transacciones, algo cono **int historial[] = new int[ 50 ];**, y un método que recorra el array y te devuelva el valor más alto.

case 7: en este caso debes crear un método que ordene a **historial**, puedes usar **Arrays.sort( historial );** que lo deja ordenado en sentido ascendente, luego lo recorres con un for en sentido inverso e imprimes los valores ( **for( int i = historial.length -1; i > -1; i-- ) {** ).

case 9: no hacemos nada.

En todos los métodos menos en **Operador** debes comprobar si **autenticado** es verdadero, y si no debes llamar a **iniciarSesion**.

Como seguramente te habrás dado cuenta, el desarrollo tiene varias lagunas, en la compra/venta de "criptos", debería haber un "efectivo" con el que comprar y su saldo correspondiente... más sus metodos...
Espero que te sirva como orientación.

Comment: hola @marcePuente gracias por la ayuda que siempre me das,sinceramente comenze hace poco a estudiar programación y la verdad me cuesta un poquito resolver los ejercicios que nos dan en la facu,algunos puedo resolverlos por mi cuenta y otros no,así agradezco mucho la ayuda que puedan darme y sacarme las dudas que se me presentan.

Comment: Para eso estamos.